# Why R is returning a vector for r1:r2 when r2 < r1?

Tags: r, indexing, seq

I'm indexing some matrices which involves ranges in R and I'm unable to get the same result I can get in Matlab. I can do this in Matlab:
R1:R2 and when R2 is smaller than R1 it returns empty matrix for example:
2:1

In R when I do R1:R2 when R2 is smaller than R1 it returns a vector. for example:
2:1 returns [1] 2 1
What is the correct and **simple** way of achieving it in R?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in pictorial terms (for those of use who haven't used MATLAB since taking a class with Charlie van Loan 15 years ago)?

Comment: To ask another way, when typing `2:1` in R, instead of `[1] 2 1`, what output would you like to see?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess nothing, as in Matlab, i.e. `[](1x0)` (this is Octave output).

Comment: Well i'm slicing a matrix into multiple chunks (like k-fold cross validation), let's say 3 chunks, `1:R1-1`, `R1:R2-1` and `R2:end`. In the first iteration of my loop though, R1 is 1 and therefore R1-1 becomes 0 in other words, the first chunk is empty, the second chunk starts from 1 to R1 and so on. The same should happen for the last chunk.

Comment: @Pascal That is correct. I'm expecting R to respect the order of the range I'm giving to it.

Comment: Also I noticed seq(2,1,by=1) generates error. Why? It can simply return NULL or something similar.

Comment: `seq(2,1,by=-1)` is the correct syntax. In R, you can generate `1,2,3,4...` as well as `...4,3,2,1` sequences.

Comment: @Pascal  `seq(2,1,by=1)`  is correct in syntax. It's the `seq()`'s implementation that treats it as an error which I believe should simply return null, it's not just syntactically correct it also logically makes sense and makes life much easier.

Comment: No, it is not a correct syntax in R. It is `seq(1, 2, by=1)` or `seq(2, 1, by=-1)`.

Comment: @Pascal What is your definition of syntax?

Comment: @Ash. Just look it up. R is different from Matlab or Octave. If you don't like it then lump it. If you want to make a Rash then get the source code and get on with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Length is easy to use and can be used in a loop to generate appropriate values. Here is the best and simplest answer I can think of:

```
seq(R1,R2,length = max(0,R2-R1+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this could work:

```
matlab_like <- function(x,y) unlist(ifelse(y >= x, list(c(x:y)), 0L))
#> matlab_like(1,3)
#[1] 1 2 3
#> matlab_like(3,1)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: perhaps instead of `NA` the value `integer(0)` might be more appropriate. Really depends on what OP wants preserved

Comment: `0L != integer(0)` The value `integer(0)` means a vector of integers of length zero.

Comment: Agreed, but if I insert `integer(0)` as the return value for the false case, then I may as well simply return `NA` directly, because my function then returns `NA`.

Comment: Truth be told, I'm not even sure if a function in `R` can return a vector of zero length.

Comment: A function can return a vector of zero length but `ifelse` can't, so you can do  `matlab_like <- function(x,y)if(y >= x){x:y}else{integer(0)}` or even `matlab_like <- function(x,y)if(y >= x){x:y}else{NULL}`.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining your own Matlab-like integer-sequence operator?

```
> `%:%` <- function (a, b) if (b >= a) a:b

> letters[2 %:% 5]
[1] "b" "c" "d" "e"
> letters[5 %:% 2]
character(0)
> letters[5 %:% 5]
[1] "e"
```

John